# The connection problem in the graphql-flutter mobile app and the server created by Graphene-Django

Tags: flutter, graphql, connection, graphene-python, graphene-django

I have a simple graphql-server created using the Graphene-Django package. Now I can test the query and mutation successfully in the desktop browser at http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql.
For testing the query and mutation in the mobile app, I made a simple flutter mobile app using the graphql_flutter package. My flutter app works properly with Hasura and Heroku graphql endpoint. But  it doesn't work with my Graphene-Django graphql endpoint. when I try to run my mobile app, it gives an error message:

**ClientExceptation: Failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql.**

Please help me for solving the problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve above mentioned problem.I exempt my Graphql endpoint from CSRF protection by wrapping the GraphQLView with the csrf_exempt decorator in urls.py file in django project, just same as this (see the [source](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/installation/) ):

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from graphene_django.views import GraphQLView
from cookbook.schema import schema

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^graphql$', csrf_exempt(GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True,schema=schema))),
]
```

it should be mention that i used 'http://my-IPv4-address:8000/graphql' in flutter app for successfully connection after above mentioned modification in CSRF Protection settings.
for achieving IPv4-address follow this [guide](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-find-your-local-and-external-ip-address-5833108). after that, i added my-IPv4-address to ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py file like this:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.x.xxx', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']
```

and finally for running graphene-django server i use this command in cmd console:

```
(env) python ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```